# How do get a function value to $_POST

Tags: php

So I am trying to get this function that is a state dropdown selection for form to give me the value of what is selected when submitted using $_POST in another file the thing is I don't really know how to when your using 'name=' a parameter that is sent in.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" ><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>
                <? if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>


<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner"><?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>
```

Thank you!

UPDATED_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

file that value is sent to ---

```
 $selectvalue=$_POST['hiddenfield'];
    echo $selectvalue;
```

main file!

```
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    // Get the index of selected item
    var list = document.getElementById('state');
    var INDEX = list.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value=list[INDEX].value;

    //Submit the form
    document.forms["theform"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
    <div class="InputContainer">
    <!------------------------------------------STATE SELECTION CODE ------------------------------------------->
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" ><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>

                <?  if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>




<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner">
<?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?>
 </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield" value="">
<?php

 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
```

updated------------------------------------------------------------------------
main file-------------

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    // Get the index of selected item
    var list = document.getElementById('state');
    var INDEX = list.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value=list[INDEX].value;

    //Submit the form
    document.forms["theform"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include('Main.css');

$hostname="";
$username="";
$password="";
$database="";

/*mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");*/

//function getFN(){
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //$DBH->prepare('SELECT first FROM contacts');
}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}  
//get query
$FNresult=$DBH->query('SELECT CompanyNames FROM companynames'); 
//set fetch mode
$FNresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$DBH = null; 
?>


        <div id="MainContainer">   
            <h2 align="center">
                <u>PLEASE SUPPLY THE FOLLOWING INFORMATION REGARDING YOUR AUTO INSURANCE POLICY:</u>
           </h2>

         <div class="FormContainer">
            <form name="theform" action="insert.php" method="post">
                <div class="CheckBoxContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="only-thisform"/>I will complete the insurance verification form only. 
            <?php 
            $setError=$_GET['seterror'];

            if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
            }
             ?>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="approval" id="approval"/>I agree to authorize PCG Protects, LLC to receive a certificate of liability and or to be added as an additional interest on my personal auto policy, whichever accommodates my Auto Insurance Carriers standard practice, so they can monitor the active status of my personal auto policy, on behalf of my employer.
             <?php 
             $setError=$_GET['seterror'];
             if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
             }

             ?>
            </div><!------------------------------------END   .CheckBoxContainer ------------------------------------------->
            <br>
            <br>


<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->


<div class="DropDownSelector">
<?php

$dropdown = "<select name='CompanyNames' id='CompanyNames' >";

$dropdown .= "\r\n<option  id ='other' name ='other' value='other'>other</option>";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  id ='firstname' name ='first' value='{$row['CompanyNames']}'>{$row['CompanyNames']}</option>";
}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
?>
    <div class="DropdownDiscription">Please select your insurance company.  Select other if you do not see it listed. </div>
</div> <!------------------------------------------END .DropDownSelector -------------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">  

var dropdown = $('#CompanyNames');
//var test = $('#firstname');
//document.write(dropdown.val());

dropdown.bind('change', function(){

    $.post('backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            'CompanyNames': dropdown.val()

        },
        function(response) {
            $('#compname').val(response.Companyname);
            //$('#phone').val(response.phone);
            //$('#policynum').val(response.policynum);
            //$('#nameofPolicyholder').val(response.policyholder);
            //$('#mailing').val(response.mailing);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );

});
</script>
<br>
<div class="FormBody">
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Insurance Company Name: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="compname" id="compname" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->

<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Insurance Phone number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name ="policynum" id="policynum"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Name of the Policyholder: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="nameofPolicyholder" id="nameofPolicyholder"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policyholder mailing address: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="mailing" id="mailing"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">City: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
    <!------------------------------------------STATE SELECTION CODE ------------------------------------------->
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" ><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>

                <?  if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>




<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner">
<?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?>
 </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield" value="">
<?php

 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<?php 
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please check to make sure all required fields are filled out!');</script>";
}
?>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" >

</div><!-------------------------------------------END .FormBody ------------------------------------------------------->
</form>


    </div><!--------------------------------------End .FormContainer ---------------------------------------------->

</div><!----------------------------------End #MainContainer----------------------------------->

</body>
</html>
```

other file----------------
everything is commenteed off except for that one display code
    /
        /**************************************VALIDATE CHECK BOXES ARE CHECKED* ****************************************************/
            /*  $setError = 0;
                $ch1 = 'unchecked';
                $ch2 = 'unchecked';
            //  print_r("testing ch1 : $ch1");
                if(isset($_POST['only-thisform']))  {

```
                $ch1 = 'Check';
                //if ($setChecker != 1)
                $setError= 0;
                //print_r("testing ch1: $ch1");

            }
            if ($ch1 !='Check' ){

            $setError = 1;
            returnBack();

        }
            if (isset($_POST['approval'])) {
                //$setChecker = 1;
                $ch2 = 'Check';
                $setError= 0;
                //print_r("testing  ch2: $ch2");
            }
             if ($ch2 != 'Check' ){

            $setError = 1;
            returnBack();

        }*/
/***************************************************************************************************************************************/       
        /* 
function returnBack(){
    header("Location: http://pcgprotects.com/PCG/test.php?seterror=1");
    exit;

}


if(isset($_POST['compname']))  {
    $compname=$_POST['compname'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}

if(isset($_POST['phone']))  {
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}

if(isset($_POST['policynum']))  {
    $policynum=$_POST['policynum'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}

if(isset($_POST['nameofPolicyholder']))  {
    $nameofPolicyholder=$_POST['nameofPolicyholder'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}

if(isset($_POST['mailing']))  {
    $mailing=$_POST['mailing'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}
if(isset($_POST['city']))  {
    $city=$_POST['city'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}
if(isset($_POST['mailing']))  {
    $mailing=$_POST['mailing'];
}
else{
    $setError = 1;
    returnBack();
}
*/

    echo "hiddenfield=".$_POST['hiddenfield'];

/*
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$new_id_number = mysql_insert_id();
$query = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('$new_id_number','$compname','$phone','$policynum','$nameofPolicyholder','$mailing')";
echo 'being inserted';
mysql_query($query);

if ('SELECT * FROM companynames WHERE CompanyNames != :compname');{
    $query = "INSERT INTO companynames VALUES('$new_id_number','$compname')";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo "working";
}
mysql_close();*/
?>
```

Comment: Your question is about how to deal with name=<?=$name;?>, is that right? Why are you using a variable name for the select in the first place? The best I can think of is to put the name in a hidden field in the form.

Comment: don't really understand the question but if you add print_r($_POST); you will see what values you get in the post array

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Dagon I want to grab that value in another file so i can store it in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? and to the other php file use $selectvalue=$_POST['hiddenfield']

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    // Get the index of selected item
    var list = document.getElementById('state');
    var INDEX = list.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value=list[INDEX].value;

    //Submit the form
    document.forms["theform"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="otherfile.php" method="post" name="theform">
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onchange="submitform()"><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>
                <? if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>


<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner"><?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

?>

and in the otherfile.php
type this, you can get the value

```
<?php
echo "hiddenfield=".$_POST['hiddenfield'];
?>
```

Comment: Hey nothing happened... i submited and didnt get the value in other file which is $state = $_POST['hiddenfield'];
 echo ("your state is  $state");

Comment: oh and i do have other java script code just so you know but that is for autofilling in forms.  what is the 'state' for in the code, where is that?

Comment: well the 'state' is the id of the option select element, it works for me, what are you doing? let me check the code again

Comment: ill repost in my question above

Comment: em you are missing <form action="otherfile.php" method="post" name="theform"> and also you are missing the <body> element check my code and compare it to yours.. :)

Comment: you need also to add the <form action="otherfile.php" method="post" name="theform"> but type the correct name

Comment: you need to insert the form element in your code 
<form action="otherfile.php" method="post" name="theform"> to get the form submited to the new page

Comment: <form name="theform" action="insert.php" method="post"> right there

Comment: when you select a state actualy it should redirect you to index.php does it?

Comment: what happens when you change the state without pressing submit? does the redirect happen?

Comment: it switches to the selection i made?

Comment: you also need to change <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" > to 
<select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onchange="submitform()">

Comment: the redirect happens but you cant get the value? if you select the state now after you insterted the onchange event, doesnt the page redirect?

Comment: no i mean i got no erros everything works i still get redirected the value just i9snt there

Comment: its tough but we will solve it .. I need to know when the redirect happens, after you select the drop down? or when you press submit?

Comment: i tried putting onchange="submitform()" on the form part but nothing

Comment: <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onchange="submitform()"> where i have it to

Comment: ok and when you change the selected value does the page redirect or you need to press submit?

Comment: but when they click the state it redirects them and i dont want that until the submit botton has been clicked i just want the value

Comment: got it thanks so much man your a big awesome help and a blessing!@ really appreciate the time you took out for me!

Comment: ok remove the  document.forms["theform"].submit(); from the submitform function

Comment: He is brotha and He loves you with all His heart!

Answer (score 1):

This will submit the form, you need to add a form element and submit it with the onchange event added on the select element, I hope this helps

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    document.forms["theform"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="otherfile.php" method="post" name="theform">
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onchange="submitform()"><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>
                <? if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>


<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner"><?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can put the function in a hidden input box and put the function in value of input box?

Comment: you can't hide the function, but do you need to get the selected value from the list?

Comment: yes I already have stuff submitted to a file in form action...i just want to get the value $_POST['name'] so i can assign it to a variable

Comment: with this function you can get the value and add it to a hidden field

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
 // Get the index of selected item
 var list = document.getElementById('state');
 var INDEX = list.selectedIndex;
 document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value=list[INDEX].value;
 
 //Submit the form
    document.forms["theform"].submit();
}
</script>

Comment: You mean get the variable from the posted file?

Comment: you can always use  $variableposted=$_POST['state']; or $_REQUEST['state'] if the name of the select list is state

Comment: THe fact is the name of the select is name=<?=$name;?>

Comment: so you mean you don't know the name?

Comment: what does the <?=$name;?> return? why dont you use that name?

Comment: how do i use that in $_POST[]?

Comment: i know how to if you have an input field name but i dont get it if you have it as a variable